# Trying to calculate user whos spent the most and the least - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet of user transactions and naturally some users will have one or more transactions. My objective is to add up the total(spent) of each user ( not necessary display it  )and display the user whos spent the most and spent the least.

I cannot use a pivot table and if you can show me the formula with the simple table below that would be very helpful.

I have tried the `max` and `averageIF` functions, but I can't get the code to work. This is just a sample table but concept will apply.

UserID      |  Amount

```
1     |      122        
2     |      400        
3     |      122        
1     |      300        
4     |      400        
5     |      100        
2     |      50     
1     |      600        
3     |      400        
2     |      320
```

So the end result will be User with Max spend  = 1 and Min spend = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in Excel 2013. They are array formulas so you have to press ctrl+shift+enter to input them. This assumes column A is your ID and column B is your amount.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(MAX(SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,A1:A10,$B$1:$B$10)),SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,A1:A10,$B$1:$B$10),0))

=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(MIN(SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,A1:A10,$B$1:$B$10)),SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,A1:A10,$B$1:$B$10),0))
```

Comment: Hmmmm, looks simpler than my solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and I have a solution, but as I can't just paste the excel sheet it's a bit hard to explain. I try anyway...

Assuming your data starts at A2 and B2 with UserID and Amount, then we have the following captions in row 1: UserID, Amount, Cumulation, Usertotals (over columns D1 and E1), Min, Max, Min spender, Max spender.

- sort the data according to UserID ascending
- in C2 put the formula `=IF(A2=A1;B2+C1;B2)` and copy it down for each data row. This cumulates the amounts together.
- in D2 put the formula `=IF(A2=A3;"";A2)` and copy it down for each data row. This leaves only the user id for the total amount there and eliminates the other noise.
- in E2 put the formula `=IF(A2=A3;"";C2)` and copy it down for each data row. This leaves only the total amount of each user there and eliminates the other noise.
- in B13 (after the last data row in column B) put the formula `=MIN(E2:E11)` to determine the minimum amount.
- in B14 (after the B13 minimum value) put the formula `=MAX(E2:E11)` to determine the maximum amount.
- in F2 put the formula `=B13` and in F3 `=F2` and copy it down for each data row. This is just to simplify access to the minimum value.
- in G2 put the formula `=B14` and in G3 `=G2` and copy it down for each data row. This is just to simplify access to the maximum value.
- in H2 put the formula `=IF(F2=E2;D2;"")` and copy it down for each data row. This determines the user that spent the least money.
- in I2 put the formula `=IF(G2=E2;D2;"")` and copy it down for each data row. This determines the user that spent the most money.
- in A13 (after the last data row in column A) put the formula `=MAX(H2:H11)` to transfer the user that spent the least amount.
- in A14 (after the minimum amount user) put the formula `=MAX(I2:I11)` to transfer the user that spent the most amount of money.
- hide column C to I.

I hope I didn't make any mistakes translating the formulas from my German excel (it's not a great idea to also translate keywords, Microsoft!).